# grep between pattern and exclude start/end pattern in output

Tags: grep

I have file.txt from which I need to grep first occurrence of a pattern. How can I grep and get matched string only ':whitespace' and 'end of line'
I m trying below command

```
cat file.txt |  grep -m1 -P "(:\s+).*ccas-apache$"
```

But it gives me

> name: nginx-ccas-apache

and I want is

> nginx-ccas-apache

```
file.txt

pod: nginx-ccas-apache-0
        name: nginx-ccas-apache
        image: myregnapq//ccas_apache
        name: nginx-filebeat
pod: nginx-ccas-apache-1
        name: nginx-ccas-apache
        image: myregnapq/ccas_apache
        name: nginx-filebeat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach using `sed`:

```
sed -En '/^[[:space:]]+name:[[:space:]](.*ccas-apache)$/{s//\1/p;q}' file.txt
```

**Explanation**

- `-En` Use extended regexp with `-E` and prevent the default printing of a line by sed with `-n`
- `/^[[:space:]]+name:[[:space:]](.*ccas-apache)$/` The pattern that specifies what to match
- If the previous pattern matched, run commands between the curly brackets
- `s//\1/p` Use the last matched pattern with `//` and replace with group 1. Then print the pattern space with `p`
- `q` exit sed

The regex matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[[:space:]]+name:[[:space:]]` Match `name:` with leading spaces and single space after
- `(.*ccas-apache)` Capture group 1, match optional chars and `ccas-apache`
- `$` End of string

Output

```
nginx-ccas-apache
```

Note that you don't have to use `cat`

See an [online demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUHXNU9BXT8uOtqquCAxOdUqNlY7LzE31QpJQENPKzk5sVg3EcjPSNVU0a8u1tePMdQvsC6sVVewsbFRUCrIT7FSyEvPzKvQRVKqa8ClAAVgMzFVwOUzcxPTgQpyK4tS0/MSCwr19UGq4tFUIZuSlpmTmpSaWMKFw25D8u0m1mql//8B).

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -Pom1 'name: \K.*$' file.txt
nginx-ccas-apache
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`, too:

```bash
awk -F: '/:[[:space:]].*ccas-apache$/{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "", $2); print $2; exit}'  file
```

*Details*:

- `-F:` - a colon is used as a field separator
- `:[[:space:]].*ccas-apache$` - searches for a line with `:`, a whitespace, then any text, `ccas-apache` at the end of the string, and once found
- `sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "", $2)` - remove the initial whitespaces from Field 2
- `print $2` - then print the Field 2 value
- `exit` - stop processing the file.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/neUSVU):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='pod: nginx-ccas-apache-0
        name: nginx-ccas-apache
        image: myregnapq//ccas_apache
        name: nginx-filebeat
pod: nginx-ccas-apache-1
        name: nginx-ccas-apache
        image: myregnapq/ccas_apache
        name: nginx-filebeat'

awk -F: '/:[[:space:]].*ccas-apache$/{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "", $2); print $2; exit}' <<< "$s"
```

Output: `nginx-ccas-apache`

Answer (score 1):

**INPUT**

```
pod: nginx-ccas-apache-0
        name: nginx-ccas-apache
        image: myregnapq//ccas_apache
        name: nginx-filebeat
pod: nginx-ccas-apache-1
        name: nginx-ccas-apache
        image: myregnapq/ccas_apache
        name: nginx-filebeat
```

**CODE**

- *enter any properly-escaped pattern for* `__` *that includes the string tail* `$`

  - *3 ways of saying the same thing*
  - *any one solution works in* `gawk`, `mawk-1`, `mawk-2`, or `macos nawk`

```
mawk '_{exit} _=$(NF=NF)~__' FS='^.*[ \t]' __='ccas-apache$' OFS=
or
gawk '_{exit} NF*=_=$(NF)~__' FS='^.*[ \t]' __='ccas-apache$' OFS=
or
nawk '_{exit} _=NF*=$NF~__' FS='^.*[ \t]' __='ccas-apache$' OFS=
```

**OUTPUT**

```
nginx-ccas-apache
```

**GENERIC SOLUTION**

- *not just at the tail*
- *this time enter pattern at* `FS`

**CODE**

```
{m,g}awk '_{exit} _=(!_<NF)*sub("[^ \t]*"(FS)"[^ \t]*","\4&\4")*\
                    gsub("^[^\4]*\4|\4[^\4]*$","")' FS='your_pattern_here'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FS='image' 

    >>> `image:`

FS='myregnapq'

    >>> `myregnapq//ccas_apache`
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F':[[:space:]]+' '
$1~/^[[:space:]]+name$/ && $2~/^[^-]*-ccas-apache$/{
  print $2
  exit
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as colon followed by space(1 or more occurrences). In main program checking condition if first field matches regex starts with space followed by name AND 2nd field matches regex `^[^-]*-ccas-apache$` then printing 2nd field of that line and `exit from program.